# How can I make my program available as native image available via apt-get?

Tags: apt

I have a github project which can be compiled to native image. How can I make it available for people to install it via `apt-get`? I am okay with uploading just the native image to a central repository as well because this project mostly won't have any updates.

Comment: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA